# Ошибка сегментирования в Си

Tags: c++, c, односвязный-список, выделение-памяти, сегментация

Задача заключается в следующем: конкатенация одинаковых по номеру строк заданных текстовых файлов, имена которых передаются через аргументы командной строки. Склеенный текст отображается через стандартный вывод, где подстроки разделены символом табуляции по умолчанию или любым другим, который указан после ключа –s в командной строке.

При last->next = tmp в методе pushBack вылазит ошибка сегментирования (стек памяти сброшен на диск). Пытался по разному переписывать и пробовать, все ошибка не пропадает.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
char value[1024];
struct Node *next;
} Node;

void push(Node **head, char data[1024]) {
Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
strcat(tmp->value, data);
tmp->next = (*head);
(*head) = tmp;
}

Node* getLast(Node *head) {
if (head == NULL) {
return NULL;
}
while (head->next) {
head = head->next;
}
return head;
}

void pushBack(Node *head, char value[1024]) {

Node *last = getLast(head);
Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
strcat(tmp->value, value);
tmp->next = NULL;
last->next = tmp;
}

void print(const Node* head) {
if (head) {
printf("%s", head->value);
print(head->next);
}
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
char tab ='\t';
int len = 1;
int bol = 0;

while ((len < argc) && (bol != 1))
{
if (strcmp(argv[len], "-s") == 0)
{
if (argc == (len + 1)) return 1;
tab = *(argv[len+1]);
bol = 1;
}
else len++;
};

FILE *f[len-1];

for (int i = 1; i < len; i++)
{
if ((f[i] = fopen(argv[i], "r")) == NULL) {
printf("Ошибка при открытии %d файла!\n", i);
return 2;
}
}
char buf[256];

Node *head = NULL;

while ((fgets(buf,256,f[1])) != NULL)
{
pushBack(head, buf);
}

for (int i=1; i < len; i++)
fclose(f[i]);

print(head);
printf("\n");

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Так-же как в `push` передавайте указатель на указатель начала списка. И проверяйте пустой-ли был список.

```
void pushBack(Node * * head, char value[1024]) {
  Node *tmp = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
  strcat(tmp->value, value);  
  tmp->next = NULL;
  if ( * head ) {
    Node *last = getLast(*head);
    last->next = tmp; }
  else
    * head = tmp ;
}
```